# Promise.all on array of promises with parameter

Tags: javascript, object, promise

How can I add an array of promises to `Promise.all` when a parameter is passed to each promise?

For example;

```js
var config = {
  name: [
    function(val) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve('This is ok')
      })
    },
    function(val) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve('This is ok')
      })
    }
  ],
  gender: [
    function(val) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve('This is ok')
      })
    },
    function(val) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        reject('This is NOT ok')
      })
    }
  ]
}
```

I essentially want to to do `Promise.all(config[name], ...)`. This will actually take place within a loop so that I can iterate over a form object, passing each key to get an array of associated promises and passing the value to each promise.

**EDIT** [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/karlbateman/keqnrybq/) which implements the accepted answer, for the curious.

Comment: your fiddle is dead

Comment: @Rohmer link updated

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to call the functions and return an array of promises.

```
Promise.all(config[name].map(callback => callback(val))
   .then(values => { 
       // executed when all promises resolved, 
       // values is the array of values resolved by the promises
   })
   .catch(err => {  
     // catch if single promise fails to resolve
   });
```

You can read more about Promise.all [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).